# Manipulating text and text files using cmd

Tags: cmd

I have a cmd script, running on win XP, that outputs a text file:

```
:start
>outputfile.txt (findstr /v "^#" info.txt || echo No text available)
ping 127.0.0.1
goto start
```

It checks for data in info.txt and if it doesn't begin with # creates outputfile.txt containing the same text. The ping is just used as a simple delaying tactic.

Now I need something similar to take the data from info.txt (providing it doesn't start with #) and add it to what is already in outputfile.txt. But only if the text in info.txt has changed! (Changing > to >> will give lots of repeats of the same text).

This is making my brain hurt. Please give me some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set DataFile=info.txt
set OutputFile=outputfile.txt
set SavedSize=0

goto start

:filesize
set CurrentSize=%~z1
exit /b

:start
call :filesize %DataFile%
if %SavedSize% neq %CurrentSize% (>%OutputFile% (findstr /v "^#" %DataFile% || echo No text available))
set SavedSize=%CurrentSize%
ping 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto start
```

The idea is to save previous data file size and wait until it will be changed.

This is not an ideal solution (because we need to copy all data from `info.txt` for each file change) and it may not work properly if someone would delete lines from `info.txt` while the script is running. It would be better to use some hash algorithm (eg, MD5), but unfortunately the standard set of CMD tools doesn't contain anything suitable.

If these limitations are crucial for you, I suggest to use some command-line hashing utility (eg, [this](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/)) or some sort of more powerful scripting language (Python, Perl, Powershell).